# BuildTemplate Edits: TFS Community Build Extensions: TFSVersion Build Activity - SourceDirectory problems

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2013, build-process

I'm trying to follow  TFSVersion Build Activity[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86n3L.png)   to edit my TFS build template.

My default template (and some added activities following the instructions above) for TFS 2013 looks like this: [image: template]

I can't get workflow working. Here are the the issues:

1. I read that SourcesDirectory is in the WellKnownEnvironmentVariables in namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.  But when i try to use the SourcesDirectory in the "Find the AssemblyInfo File" activity. it tells me it is not declared. i thought you are not supposed to declare it because it's already known? i have the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities referenced.  what else do i need?
2. The instructions say to locate GetWorkspace in your default template.  My default template doesn't have that.  Do i need to add it under associate changesets?  or can i use something from the Initialize Environment activity.  But when i look there.. all i see is "src".  not ever sure what that is. Do i need to do a GetWorkspace at all if the template uses the Init Env Act?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow: SourcesDirectory[1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/034f792b-0b09-4174-b4ba-e40eeb16e6f6/how-to-get-the-sources-directory-in-tfs-2013)

Yes, apparently you need to use GetEnvironmentVariable activity to get the SourcesDirectory (for TFS 2013). (Save the result in a local variable to be used by the FindMatchingFiles Activity)

In my case i also needed to use the FULL Path of the SourcesDirectory variable. Since even though i have it listed under the imports, it didn't resolve "WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory".

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory

Also i did NOT need to use GetWorkspace.

Comment: Can you please expand on how you got this to work?  Your post helped clarify I don't need that GetWorkspace thing and that I need the GetEnvironmentVariable to have the SourcesDirectory in the Find AssemblyInfoFiles thing but I have no idea how to "save the result in a local variable" or what else exactly I might need.  If you could outline all the pieces that would be a huge help.  Thanks.